# Pytorch equivalent of tensorflow keras StringLookup?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I'm working with pytorch now, and I'm missing a layer: `tf.keras.layers.StringLookup` that helped with the processing of ids. Is there any workaround to do something similar with pytorch?

An example of the functionality I'm looking for:

```
vocab = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
data = tf.constant([["a", "c", "d"], ["d", "a", "b"]])
layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)
layer(data)

Outputs:
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[1, 3, 4],
       [4, 1, 2]])>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package torchnlp,

```
pip install pytorch-nlp
```

```
from torchnlp.encoders import LabelEncoder

data = ["a", "c", "d", "e", "d"]
encoder = LabelEncoder(data, reserved_labels=['unknown'], unknown_index=0)

enl = encoder.batch_encode(data)

print(enl)
```

```
tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 3])
```

Comment: Does that solution support sending a pytorch tensor and receiving a pytorch tensor? (similar to tf) Doing the operations on a python list level will bottlenet gpu execution code

Comment: Not sure if you want to avoid a list as input. As you know there's no direct conversion of list of strings to pytorch tensor.

Comment: I edited your comment with batch_encode to better suit the case, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Collections.Counter` along with [`torchtext`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/text_sentiment_ngrams_tutorial.html)'s `vocab` object to construct a lookup function from your vocabulary. You can then easily pass sequences to this and get their encodings as a tensor:

```py
from torchtext.vocab import vocab
from collections import Counter

tokens = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
samples = [["a", "c", "d"], ["d", "a", "b"]]

# Build string lookup
lookup = vocab(Counter(tokens))
```

```py
>>> torch.tensor([lookup(s) for s in samples])
tensor([[0, 2, 3],
        [3, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the library torchtext,
just install it with python3 -m pip install torchtext

and you can is like this:

```
from torchtext.vocab import vocab
from collections import OrderedDict

tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
v1 = vocab(OrderedDict([(token, 1) for token in tokens]))
v1.lookup_indices(["a","b","c"])
```

and this is the result:

```
([0, 1, 2],)
```

Comment: Does that solution support sending a pytorch tensor and receiving a pytorch tensor? (similar to tf) Doing the operations on a python list level will bottlenet gpu execution code

Comment: Yes but it should be a 1D tensor so you will beed some manipulations to your xode